# Angular spring boot into one project and one port

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have angular project and spring boot project. I have configured both into one. 
Here is the folder structure:

```
Angular_SpringBoot
 -src
   -main
     -java
     -angularweb
   -resources
     app.properties.
 build.gradle
```

In my build.gradle file I've defined like below,

```
def webappDir = "$projectDir/src/main/angular-web"
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["$webappDir/dist", "$projectDir/src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}

processResources {
    dependsOn "buildAngular"
}

task buildAngular(type:Exec) {
    dependsOn "installAngular"
    workingDir "$webappDir"
    inputs.dir "$webappDir"
        commandLine "ng.cmd", "build", "--prod"

}
task installAngular(type:Exec) {
    workingDir "$webappDir"
    inputs.dir "$webappDir"
        commandLine "npm.cmd", "install"

}
```

Now If I run the project from command prompt(gradle bootRun) the project gets build and can be accessed.
But when the run the same form spring boot dashboard the web project is not showing in browser.
I want to run the project from springboot dashboard say for ex: If I change any thing in any angularWeb and I restart, the changes should be reflected (like ng serve normally happens - in angularweb)

I've tried creating parent project containing  two child projects i.e, frontend and backend with two build.gradle files, also tried configuring the same proxy in angular-cli.json.
I've followed
https://dzone.com/articles/building-a-web-app-using-spring-boot-angular-6-and

https://dzone.com/articles/angular-2-and-spring-boot-development-environment

Also my properties file should be like app-dev.propeties, app-prod.properties (not like environment.dev.ts, environment.prod.ts), so that I can build the project from spring boot properties files (like all the baseurl, build commands should be in .properties file)

None of the methods haven't worked for me.